# Sorting timespan using linq with custom string requirement

Tags: c#, linq

I have a scenario where I have a list of timespans along with a string field that indicates whether the timespan should be in the top 16 of the 20 timespans that I have.
Example:

`TIME    Type
1:58.33 auto
2:02.87 auto
2:06.18 auto
2:13.70 auto
2:28.17 time
2:30.85 time
2:31.25 time
2:40.25 auto
2:40.36 time
2:59.35 auto
3:05.33 time
3:09.32 time
3:38.67 alternate
3:56.61 alternate
...`

What I need is that all list items that have "auto" as the type to remain in the top 16 regardless of the time after sorting. Those with time (or other values) can drop below the 16th item.

What I had in mind was to sort the list by time with **some method of preventing auto from going below 16**. Then I can set 17-20 as alternate. I just have no idea how to go about it using linq which I assume will be the best way.

Comment: What if there are more than 16 with type "auto"?

Comment: In my scenario, not possible. We have 3 meets that feed into one meet and the top 3 placers from the 3 meets are automatic regardless of time. So it should never be more than 9, and it can be less than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like another way to state the problem is: "All items with 'auto' plus the 4 fastest without 'auto'".

```
var a = list.Where(x => x.Type == "auto").OrderBy(x => x.Time);
var b = list.Where(x => x.Type != "auto").OrderBy(x => x.Time).Take(4);
var result = a.Concat(b);
```

Answer (score 1):

To control how a class is sorted you can make the class implement [IComparable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd(v=vs.110).aspx) or create a separate class that implements [IComparer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf(v=vs.110).aspx).

The difference is that implementing `IComparable<T>` specifies a default sort order, which makes sense if there's something intrinsic, obvious sort order that would usually apply. But in other cases you may have more than one way that you want to sort a class. An example of that are the various `StringComparer` classes the .NET framework provides. They are all implementations of `IComparer<string>`.

I don't have your class, so I made up this one:

```
public class TimeSpanWithType
{
    public TimeSpan Time { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

Here's a comparer class that sorts classes with type "auto" first.

```
public class AutoFirstComparer : IComparer<TimeSpanWithType>
{
    public int Compare(TimeSpanWithType x, TimeSpanWithType y)
    {
        if (x.Type!=y.Type)
        {
            if (x.Type == "auto") return -1;
            if (y.Type == "auto") return 1;
        }
        return x.Time.CompareTo(y.Time);
    }
}
```

Then for convenience, here's a static class so that you don't have to keep creating new instances of your comparer.

```
public static class TimeSpanWithTypeComparison
{
    public static IComparer<TimeSpanWithType> AutoFirst = new AutoFirstComparer();
}
```

Here's a unit test demonstrating that when sorting it puts "auto" first.

```
[TestClass]
public class TimeSpanWithTypeComparisonTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void SortsAsExpected()
    {
        var time1 = new TimeSpanWithType() { Type = "xyz", Time = TimeSpan.FromHours(1) };
        var time2 = new TimeSpanWithType() { Type = "auto", Time = TimeSpan.FromHours(3) };
        var time3 = new TimeSpanWithType() { Type = "auto", Time = TimeSpan.FromHours(2) };
        var sorted = new TimeSpanWithType[] { time1, time2, time3 }
            .OrderBy(t => t, TimeSpanWithTypeComparison.AutoFirst).ToArray();
        Assert.AreEqual(sorted[0], time3);
        Assert.AreEqual(sorted[1], time2);
        Assert.AreEqual(sorted[2], time1);
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks extremely close to what I need. Does this put all auto results first though? The tricky part I have is auto just needs to be in the top 16 (essentially guaranteeing that they compete). So it could end up with timespans that are auto, auto, time, time, auto, time, auto, etc. Make sense?

Comment: All auto results are first.